# Rails rake task not executing in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, pdf-generation, rake, wkhtmltopdf

I have been working on a Ruby on Rails project (a basic survey application using the 'surveyor' gem) that lets a user download a pdf of the completed survey results. To accomplish, I have written a basic rake task (as below) that calls the wkhtmltopdf command line utility to convert from HTML/CSS to a pdf every 15 minutes via whenever/cron.

Here is the rake task (`lib/tasks/pdf_survey_results.rake`):

```
desc "PDF Completed Survey Results for Admin Download"

task :pdf_survey_results => :environment do

  # iterate through all the response sets
  ResponseSet.all.each do |response_set|

    if !response_set.completed_at.blank?
      puts "response set #{response_set.id} is complete, checking for pdf..."

      if response_set.pdf_url.blank?
        puts "no pdf found, now generating..."

        # make the pdf
        result = system "wkhtmltopdf #{BASE_URL}/surveys/student-questionnaire/#{response_set.access_code} /opt/deployed_rails_apps/survey_app/public/survey-pdfs/survey-#{response_set.access_code}.pdf"
        if !result.nil?
          response_set.pdf_url = "#{BASE_URL}/survey-pdfs/survey-#{response_set.access_code}.pdf"
          response_set.save
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works totally fine in my development environment (OS X) but when I have deployed to Ubuntu 14.04,

1. I CAN manually create pdf's via the command line (i.e. `wkhtmltopdf http://surveyurl.com sample.pdf`)
2. I CANNOT create pdf's via running the rake task manually (i.e. `rake pdf_survey_results` will give me the output through "no pdf found, now generating..." but none of the output from the wkhtmltopdf tool even though I DO see this output when running on my local OS X dev environment)
3. I CANNOT create pdf's via the cron job set up by whenever, which is not surprising as the manual rake task execution is not working.

What I am most stuck with is that I cannot figure out why the rake task is not giving me text output from wkhtmltopdf when it does that in Mac OS X even though the command line utility by itself works fine. So far that aspect has made this a bit difficult for me to debug. By the way, I am using unicorn as an application server in this project.

Any advice is very much appreciated!!! Will answer any relevant questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: Is `wkhtmltopdf` on the PATH for the user running unicorn? You might try using an absolute path.

Comment: if I execute `which wkhtmltopdf` then I get no output (from the admin user which is running unicorn), but if I type `sudo which wkhtmltopdf` then I get back `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`. Does that mean I should replace `wkhtmltopdf` in my rake task with `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`? Thanks!

Comment: Update: I provided an absolute path to wkthmltopdf in my rake task (i.e. replace `wkhtmltopdf` with `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`), then I executed `RAILS_ENV=production rake pdf_survey_results` manually in the bash prompt and got back this output:

`
    response set 2 is complete, checking for pdf...
    no pdf found, now generating...
    response set 3 is complete, checking for pdf...
    no pdf found, now generating...
    response set 4 is complete, checking for pdf...
    no pdf found, now generating...
`

However, there is no pdf or output from the wkhtmltopdf program.

Comment: Have you looked at the wicked_pdf or pdfkit gems? They take care of a lot of this for you.

Comment: You could also capture the `stderr` stream (`result = system "wkhtmltopdf ....pdf 2>&1"`) and output the `result` to the terminal for further debugging (`puts result`).